# Help Identifying SMD Transistor

Tags: transistors, surface-mount

What is this component?

The only markings on the component are 96 G  and M1. The board silk screen designates it letter Q so I'm thinking it's a transistor?

[image]

Please advise

Comment: Ohhh, can't be too many components that look like that. My guess is an RF transistor. The Q in Q13 means a BJT.

Comment: It could help if you provide another picture with the entire PCB. For those situations, we have to guess for what purpose the TR is used, in which a pic of the entire PCB helps a lot.

Comment: +1 on DKNguyen. Looks like and RF HEMT capsule.

Comment: Well that's a rare package to see. Only ever seen that on RF stuff, so it's probably an RF transistor. Going to disagree with @DKNguyen though; I use Q all the time for any transistor, regardless of whether it's a BJT, JFET, MOSFET, or IGBT.

Comment: @Hearth I think Q is used for BJT and IGBTs. I tend to see M used for MOSFETs. I can't remember what is used for JFETs. I don't think it's M though.

Comment: @DKNguyen I've seen M for MOSFETs, but only rarely, and usually in older textbooks. It may be an older norm that's become less common? Or it could be that it's just not common in the US, since I know there are a fair number of differences between American and European standard practices.

Comment: It's part of an RF control. I added more pictures. Thanks everyone.